# How to return the a formatted response from a mongo query/projection?

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm trying to create an API to validate a promocode. I have minimal experience with mongo and the backend in general so I'm a bit confused in what is the best approach to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have this PromoCode form in the client. When a user types a promocode I would like for my backend to

1. verify if the code exists in one of the `docs`.
2. if it exists then return that `code`, the `value` for that code  and the `couponId`
3. if the code doesn't exist then return an error.

My `db` is  structured like this. The user will type one of those codes inside the `codes: []`

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "603f7a3b52e0233dd23bef79"
    },
    "couponId": "rate50",
    "value": 50,
    "codes": ["K3D01XJ50", "2PACYFN50", "COKRHEQ50"]
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "603f799d52e0233dd23bef78"
    },
    "couponId": "rate100",
    "value": 100,
    "codes": ["rdJ2ZMF100", "GKAAYLP100", "B9QZILN100"]
}
```

My route is structure like this:

```js
router.post('/promoCode', (req, res, next) => {

  const { promoCode } =  req.body;

  console.log('this is the req.body.promoCode on /promoCode', promoCode)

  if (!promoCode) {
    throw new Error('A promoCode needs to be passed')
  }

  promoCodesModel
    .validatePromoCode(req.body.promoCode)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response inside /promoCode', response)
      res.status(200).json({ data: response })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({ result: 'nok', error: error })
    })
})
```

The `validatePromoCode` function is the following:

```js
const validatePromoCode = async (code) => {
    try {
      let promoCode = await PromoCodesModel.find(
        {"codes": code},
        {_id: 0, codes: { $elemMatch: { $eq: code }} })
      console.log('This is the promocode', promoCode)
      
      return promoCode
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error (err.stack)
    }
}
```

All this seems to sort of work since I get the following response when the code is typed correctly

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "COKRHEQ50"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

when typed incorrectly I get

```json
{
    "data": []
}
```

What I would like to get back is. (How can I accomplish this ?). Thanks

```json
// when typed correctly
{
    "data": { value: 50, couponId: "rate50", code: "COKRHEQ50" }
}


// when typed incorrectly
{
    "error": "this is not valid code"
}
```

**TL;DR:** I would like to return a formatted query with specific values from a mongo query or an error object if that value does not exist on the document object.

Comment: You didn't mention where you want the output to be formatted - within the query _or_ on the query result? If you want the query to return the formatted result use an aggregation.

Comment: You return json in `res.status(200).json({ data: response })`. If you are not happy with format of the response, analyse it and craft required json to return. It's still javascript, even if running serverside.

Comment: @prasad_ I added more clarity to the question. And actual format I would like to receive from my query. I would like the query to return the formatted result.

Comment: You cannot do it from the query alone. `{"data"` part of the response comes from nodejs. You can't change it to `{"error"` on mongo side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just figured it out

To be able to get the this responsed (what I wanted):

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "K3D01XJ50"
            ],
            "couponId": "rate50",
            "value": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

I ended up having to do this on `validatePromoCode`

```js
onst validatePromoCode = async (code) => {
  try {
    let promoCode = await PromoCodesModel.find(
      { codes: code },
      { _id: 0, codes: { $elemMatch: { $eq: code } }, couponId: 1, value: 1 },
    )
    return promoCode
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.stack)
  }
}
```

But is there a better way on doing this ?  Thanks